# Passing multiple commands through xargs

Tags: bash, grep, multiprocessing, cat, xargs

I have this text file that has multiple bash commands in it. An example of something similar to it would be it like this

commands.txt ->

```
mkdir test
rm test '\t'
mkdir test1
rm test1 '\t'
mkdir test3
rm test3 '\t'
```

What I want to be able to do is get all the rm commands from text file and run them simultaneously with xargs and once its finish get all the mkdir commands and run them all at the same time as well.

I got this idea from a blog -

grep 'rm' commands.txt | while read i; do printf "%q\n" "$i"; done | xargs --max-procs=3 -I CMD bash -c CMD

This sort of works however in my commands I do have an '\t' and its not escaping it instead its just putting a t. I think this has to do with the printf. Any ideas?

Comment: Smells like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and not safe at all, you can easily shoot yourself this way. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: well the text file has a bunch of hadoop dfs -rmr commands and sqoop import commands . I want to to run the -rmr commands first then all the sqoop commands parralell. If I do it sequentially it takes to long and resources are not available for the other restore jobs.

Comment: It that a badly written script, or something?

Comment: At any rate, have a look at GNU Parallel, which is much more powerful than `xargs` and should handle this in a breeze. Take a look at the `-j,--max-procs` option, and [no command means arguments are commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#No-command-means-arguments-are-commands). You only need to read each set of lines into a separate array (with `mapfile` or a loop, see [BashFAQ/001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)).

Answer (score 0):

> This sort of works however in my commands I do have an '\t' and its
>   not escaping it instead its just putting a t. I think this has to do
>   with the printf.

You were close; this has to do with the `read`. See **[Bash Builtin Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins)**:

> `read` …
>
> `-r`
>
> If this
>   option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character. The
>   backslash is considered to be part of the line. …

Thus, it should work if you change `read i` to `read -r i`.